# MongoDB throwing connection error on cpanel, but working on development

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm running api that is integrated with mongodb, the API is hosted on cpanel for a while. It worked perfectly since 1 week when it started showing some strange connection error, while in the development environment everything is running fine.Here is the error I got on cpanel.

```
App 3765874 output:     at Mongoose.connect (/home/danai/nodevenv/danai-api/12/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:376:20)
App 3765874 output:     at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/home/danai/nodevenv/danai-api/12/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1220:10)
App 3765874 output:     at promiseOrCallback (/home/danai/nodevenv/danai-api/12/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
App 3765874 output:     at /home/danai/nodevenv/danai-api/12/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
App 3765874 output:     at /home/danai/nodevenv/danai-api/12/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:377:10
App 3765874 output:     at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/danai/nodevenv/danai-api/12/lib/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:819:32)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like MongoDB have an "allowed ips" list https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security/ip-access-list/
If you set it up in your dev environment, and then moved it without adding what ips should be allowed to connect to it in the prod environment, that might cause an issue.

Comment: @Wanscher I added 0.0.0.0/0  (includes your current IP address), and also shared IP address of cpanel in allowed ips

Comment: Maybe a protocol version issue then? What does the error say exactly?

Comment: That's all I've got in cpanel errors section. Like I said it worked fine 1 week ago, I didn't changed anything in my code

Comment: Do you know what van cause this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to white list you cpanel server ip in mongodb atlas
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security/ip-access-list/

in you mongodb atlas Dashboard
in security tab you will find network tab
in this you have to ip address of you cpanel server to whitelist it
checkout this images
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpgzq.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdgdi.png

Comment: I have allowed access from all ips

Comment: And also the cpanel ip address

Comment: can you share mongo connection code of yours

Comment: The connection code is standard, it worked 1 week ago, idk what happened

Comment: Any updates?. I tried everything and still not working